# Angularjs reset button doesn't clean all form fields with ngDisable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First days with Angularjs, so I'm sorry if the question could be trivial.

This problem happens in Chrome (Chromium) not in Firefox.

I have a form with reset button.
I saw that to use a button with type="reset" could be the more clear way to reset the form, including to clean the content of not validate input like email.

The button is disabled or not by ngDisable directive with value that comes from the controller:

```
<button ng-disabled="isUnchanged(customer)" type="reset" ng-click="reset(customer)">Reset</button>
```

where, in the controller, isUnchanged is:

```
$scope.isUnchanged = function(customer) {
    return angular.equals(customer, $scope.master);
};
```

Well, in this situation clicking on the reset button all the input fields are cleaned but NOT the email field.

Setting ng-disable="false" all works WELL.

Maybe the value of the function is read later conflicting with the default function of the button?

Comment: `return =` is a syntax error.

Comment: I would skip the reset button and just bind each form element to a model object, then just reset the model to a pristine state. The form shouldn't be anything more than a reflection of your model.

Comment: Return expression has 2 close parens. Angular catches exceptions like this and does nothing.

Comment: consider using form.$pristine instead of isUnchanged.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the paste error, in my code it is right and it was edited.

Comment: the input field are binded to a model:
<input type="email" ng-model="customer.email" name="cEmail" required /> and the reset function resets also does $scope.form.$setPristine();

Comment: tried form.$pristine (perfect solution) but still in Chromium doesn't work.

Comment: In this way works:
$scope.isUnchanged = function(customer) {
   return customer == null;
};